# Find time difference of first instance of a value and first instance of another value in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, algorithm, panel-data

I have an already sorted dataframe of panel data below, where a certain `diagnosisCode` is mapped to a positive or false value in `hasDisease`. I have 2 arrays which indicate whether a code is positive or negative

```
positiveDiagnosisCodes = [A] # corresponds to hasDisease = 1
negativeDiagnosisCodes = [B, C, D] # corresponds to hasDisease = 0
```

| ID | Date | diagnosisCode | hasDisease |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 01/01/2020 | A | 1 |
| 2 | 02/01/2020 | A | 1 |
| 2 | 03/01/2020 | B | 0 |
| 2 | 04/01/2020 | B | 0 |
| 2 | 07/01/2020 | A | 1 |
| 3 | 02/01/2020 | B | 0 |
| 3 | 03/01/2020 | A | 1 |
| 3 | 07/01/2020 | A | 1 |
| 3 | 11/01/2020 | B | 0 |
| 3 | 15/01/2020 | A | 1 |
| 3 | 18/01/2020 | A | 1 |
| 3 | 19/01/2020 | A | 1 |
| 3 | 20/01/2020 | B | 0 |
| 3 | 21/01/2020 | C | 0 |
| 3 | 22/01/2020 | A | 1 |
| 3 | 25/01/2020 | A | 1 |
| 3 | 26/01/2020 | D | 0 |
| 3 | 28/01/2020 | D | 0 |

I am interested in finding the time it takes for a patient show signs of no disease. Specifically, I want to find the time difference between the

1. the earliest timestamp where `hasDisease` = 1 and
2. *the earliest timestamp where `hasDisease` = 0

*However, this is only valid for `negativeDiagnosisCodes` not previously recorded.

---

Hence in the example above, the time difference (in days for simplicity, but actual data will be in hours) of `ID` 2 is 2 days, since the earliest timestamp where `Disease` = 1 is `01/01/2020` and the earliest timestamp where `Disease`  = 0 is `03/01/2020`.

For `ID` 3, there are 2 results - 18 days and 23 days. We take the time difference of `21/01/2020` and `03/01/2020`, where the patient is first diagnosed with code `C`. We also take the time difference of `26/01/2020` and `03/01/2020`, where the patient is first diagnosed with code `D`. We ignore the entries on `11/01/2020` and `20/01/2020` since the patient was already diagnosed with code `B` on `02/01/2020`.

---

I hope to get an output like this:

| ID | Time Difference | diagnosisCode |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 days | B |
| 3 | 18 days | C |
| 3 | 23 days | D |

---

How can I achieve this efficiently? I have tried using pandas groupby() but I am stuck on the aggregation part. Do I need to use more complex data structures like graphs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create dataframe using group by to find earliest date for each ID and DiagnosisCode.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import timedelta 
df = df.groupby(['ID', 'diagnosisCode'])[['Date']].min().unstack(1).reset_index()
df = df.droplevel(0, axis = 1)
df.rename(columns={ '': "ID" }, inplace = True)
```

After that, calculate difference date for each diagnosiscode and put nan value if difference is negative value.

```
df['Diff B'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['B'] - x['A'] if x['B'] - x['A'] > timedelta(0) else np.nan, axis=1)
df['Diff C'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['C'] - x['A'] if x['C'] - x['A'] > timedelta(0) else np.nan, axis=1)
df['Diff D'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['D'] - x['A'] if x['D'] - x['A'] > timedelta(0) else np.nan, axis=1)
```

alternatives

```
mask_B = df["B"] - df["A"] > timedelta(0) 
df.loc[mask_B ,'Diff B'] = df['B'] - df2['A'] 
mask_C = df["C"] - df["A"] > timedelta(0) 
df.loc[mask_C ,'Diff C'] = df['C'] - df['A'] 
mask_D = df["D"] - df["A"] > timedelta(0) 
df.loc[mask_D ,'Diff D'] = df['D'] - df['A']
```

Then, melt table into desired output.

```
result = pd.melt(df, id_vars='ID', value_vars=['Diff B', 'Diff C', 'Diff D']).dropna()
```

Thank you

Comment: Awesome. Any alternative to apply()? Got a big dataset and it’s taking a long time.

Comment: Try Using Mask

`mask_B = df["B"] - df["A"] > timedelta(0)
df.loc[mask_B ,'Diff B'] = df['B'] - df2['A']
mask_C = df["C"] - df["A"] > timedelta(0)
df.loc[mask_C ,'Diff C'] = df['C'] - df['A']
mask_D = df["D"] - df["A"] > timedelta(0)
df.loc[mask_D ,'Diff D'] = df['D'] - df['A']`